# Facebook/Unity OpenGraph: Object with ID ' ' cannot be retrieved

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I am currently trying to get Facebook to send an Open Graph object from within my Unity game however something weird is happening. I have the object set up within the Open Graph settings page, and I have done all of the set up required to get the actual object ID and everything. The image is hosted, the POST object data changed etc. The function I am calling contains the following:

```
FB.AppRequest(
        message: "I sent you a life!",
        actionType: Facebook.OGActionType.Send,
        objectId: livesIdValue*,
        filters: null,
        excludeIds: null,
        maxRecipients: null,
        data: "",
        title: "Send a life to your friends",
        callback: sendLifeCallback
        );
```

*livesIdValue is set to the ID that was returned from the Graph API Explorer.

The strange thing about this is, on one Facebook account, this works completely fine, and will show the Friend Picker dialog window thing. When I try it with a second Facebook account though, I get the error message:

"Object with ID 'value that is stored in livesIdValue' cannot be retrieved.

Has anybody run into this problem? I'm really not sure what could be causing this problem to only show up on one account but not the other.